# Rails link_to in templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add a link_to to a pre-made bootstrap template it ends up putting the link below the nav-icon.  I'm not sure if this is a CSS problem or if my code is wrong.

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></a></li>
```

Comment: Why are you using one link tag inside another?

Comment: I've tried it with and without the a href tag and it does the same thing.  I just pasted what I had as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to("<i class='icon-off icon-white'></i> Logout".html_safe, destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

Comment: Awesome.  Worked perfect, I forgot that I needed to include the image inside of the link_to.  Thanks!